# More pythonic way to turn list of nested dicts to tables in pandas?

Tags: python, csv, optimization, dictionary, pandas

I am trying to turn a list of nested jsons stored in a csv into two tables.
Each nest looks like this:

```
{'a': {'foo': 'bar',
 'bar': 'foo'},
 'b': {'foo': 'bar'},
 'id': '11111111',
 'c': {'foo': 'bar',
       'foo': 'bar',},
 'd': [{'id': '1111',
        'foo': 'bar',
        'foo': 'bar'},
       {'id': '1111',
        'foo': 'bar',
        'foo': 'bar'}],
 'timeStamp': '2014-02-08T06:22:32Z',
 'e': {'foo': 'bar'}}
```

The code i have so far looks like this:

```
rows=[]
products=[]
for k,j in json_series.iteritems():
    prod =j.pop('d')
    prod_df= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(prod)
    products.append(prod_df)
    nonce = j.pop('id')
    ts = j.pop('timeStamp')
    try:
        i= j.pop('key_to_ignore')
    except:
        frames=[]
        for x in j:
            frame =pd.DataFrame(j[x].values()).T
            frame.columns = j[x].keys()
            frames.append(frame)
        row = pd.concat(frames, axis=1)
        row['key'] = nonce
        row['timestamp'] = ts
        rows.append(row)
df_non_prod= pd.concat(rows)
df_prod= pd.concat(products)
```

This works, but it is seems ugly and I would like to understand how I could make it better. Storing the 1 row dataframes and concatenating them at the end is inefficient as the headers for all but one of the rows become redundant. Thanks.

Comment: There's an issue with your code, perhaps just an indentation error (not sure).

Comment: Thanks, Andy. I left out the try and except originally.

Comment: I still get a `KeyError: 'd'` with the new code (assuming obvious fix to indentation...).